# Having a problem with Normal Baking a high poly model into a low poly model. (with file included)

Tags: uv, sculpting, normals, normal-map

I'm having this issue where, yes i can bake the normal map, but when i apply it onto the lowpoly model with the normal map something weird happens in the middle of the model. I have no idea what to do.

[image]

And when i do put it into the model it looks like it has more blurry and less detail than the sculpted one even though the textures is 4k, but maybe thats just me.
I will put the file here. You can look and try for yourself. A detailed description of what i need to do would be highly appreciated!

File: http://www.mediafire.com/file/t0aom5cg990xbi9/nihilanthtest1.blend/file

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with a *32 Bit Float* image and it works fine:

[image]

Comment: Did that, still no good sadly. Heres a picture of the after if it helps
https://gyazo.com/2548d7c5e28d43b92c1895379fd04eb3
I must be doing something wrong, but i just dont know what..

Comment: Yes that's weird, I've tried again and it works, what Blender version are you using? Also make sure that the new image is selected in the Image Texture node